# undefined is not a function- Error in Sails

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am facing the following error in Sails when I run `sails lift` which is as follows

```
usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/util /schema.js:59
attributes[key].type = attributes[key].type.toLowerCase();                                                  
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at        /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/util s/schema.js:59:51
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.schema.normalizeAttributes  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/uti ls/schema.js:45:22)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/index.js:42:34)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/collection/index.js:44:8)
at new child (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/extend.js:17:39)
at initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/collection/loader.js:37:10)
at loadCollection (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:112:29)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:162:20
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:230:13
at _arrayEach (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:81:9)
at _each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:72:13)
at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:229:9)
at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:206:22)
at Array.async.auto.loadCollections (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:125:13)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:590:38
```

My model has the following attributes

```
SerialNo: {
  type: 'integer',
  unique: true,
  required: true,
  index: true
},

CreatedAt: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
}
```

I don't understand the error. I have no functions in the corresponding controller. I also have not defined any routes as of now.

Can somebody help me with this error?

Comment: You don't have to use a `createdAt` attribute which exists implicitly

Comment: The `Date` type doesn't exist in Waterline, you'll have to use `type: 'datetime'`

Comment: The `default` [attribute option](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes) doesn't exist. You can use `defaultsTo`

Comment: @YannBertrand. I did Type 'datetime ' and it worked for for me. Also when I did type='date', I still got output. Can you tell is there an difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Your Model you have to change your model like this :

```
SerialNo: {
  type: 'integer',
  unique: true,
  required: true,
  index: true
},

CreatedAt: {
  type: 'Date',
  default: Date.now
}
```

note : in sails **type** must have this **'** **'**